# how we can add queries with proximity in luwak

Tags: solr

For example, if my query is:

> "student of university"

and proximity declared is 1, and the input document has a sub-strings like:

> "student of xyz university"

or

> "student abc(any word) of xyz university"

Then it should give hit for both these document.
Means it should match full `pharse(query)` with proximity.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-

Comment: At least add some information about what you've tried